# How to persist Android Studio settings between installations, including custom shortcuts?

Tags: android-studio

I am using a git settings repository as pictured:

[image: settings repository dialog]

The repo is working fine and changes are pushed to the repo every time I close Android Studio.
Nevertheless, my custom keyboard shortcuts are not saved, so whenever I install Android Studio on a new system, although the settings from the remote repository are restored successfully, the keyboard shortcuts are not, forcing me to re-configure them all.

This is a massive loss of time.

How to sync custom keyboard shortcuts automatically?

Comment: Please don't use the Android tag for questions about Android Studio.

Comment: @Zoe fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

They were actually saved, although *not* into the default keymap layout. In my case that was called "Default for Xwin copy 2" (don't ask me why since it was a clean installation).
Anyways. Check in which layout they are saved and just restore that.